# Azure DevOps Server 2020 - Reconfigure Search

Tags: azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I recently installed Azure DevOps Server 2020 and at the time of installation I set the Search Service User to a specific AD user group that I had planned on using later on for search in TFS/Web UI.

According to the Microsoft documentation below, changing this parameter should be doable based on running the **Server Configuration Wizard** again or by launching the **Search Configuration Wizard**. However, Microsoft fails to mention how to reopen the Server Configuration Wizard or how to use/open the **Search Configuration Wizard**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops-2020#config-tfs

Following another guide to open **D:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2020\Tools\TfsMgmt.exe configure** opens the original Wizard to which the buttons are grayed out since they are already set.

Does anyone know how to relaunch or open these Wizards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the search service before you re-configure it.

You can open command prompt as administrator and navigate to Elastic search directory.

For azure devops 2019. The directory is `C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2019\Search\ES\elasticsearchv6.2\bin`.  In Azure devops 2020 the elasticsearch version might be higher.

Then run command `elasticsearch-service.bat remove`

After the search service is removed, you can go the Azure devops server administration console to reconfigure it.

If removing elastic search service doesnot work, try removing the Search feature too.
See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/administration?view=azure-devops-2020#unconfigure-search-on-the-machine-configured-as-your-azure-devops-server) for more information.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Do keep in mind for others that the uninstall process can be ran in the TFS Admin Console as well. Select the server, then on the right hand menu choose Remove Feature and select Search to uninstall.

Comment: The specific guidance for uninstalling Search is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?view=azure-devops-2020#uninstall-search